# How to change the crypto-currency that is used in paying for gas fees in a private network

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I have deployed my own network of blockchain that is based on the ethereum network. I wanted to know if one could change the currency used to pay for the gas on the private network.

Comment: This was promised by Ethereum Devs early on but as far as I can tell has never been delivered

Comment: Kind of a common theme in ETH tbh

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no easy way to do this. The ethereum protocol is designed to use its native currency for gas.

It would probably be very difficult to alter the protocol to run on an external currency. And it's probably impossible to allow *any* foreign currency, since external currencies have a potentially endless variety of implementations.